# I am trying to create a PDF such that when I type into a text field it will automatically check a checkbox for me

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

I am using a PDF editor to do this (specifically PDF X-change editor) and I have created my entire fillable form PDF.

In this form I record my encounter with patients. I am a doctor.

If I perform a specific task (a billable service that I provide) I use the form to check the box with the corresponding billing code, and then I type into an adjacent text field the details of the procedure that I did. For example, if I do a manual therapy code (97014) I check the checkbox for 97014 and then I type into the text field the area I performed therapy on. Once I click a checkbox I ALWAYS then describe the service in the adjacent text field. I would save a lot of time if the checkbox would automatically become checked if I type in the text field.

So, I will use the following names to help simplify/explain:

Checkbox id="ManualTherapy"

text field id="Description"

In summary, is it possible for me to auto check a specific checkbox if I put text into a specific text field? So I then just type into "Description" and that causes "ManualTherapy" to be checked.